# snapshot from the UIview is not displaying arcs and roundrect corner

Tags: iphone, ios, uibezierpath, quartz-core

I am making arcs on uiview by  UIBezierPath.It is doing fine arc is making but when I am taking snapshot of this UIView for sharing the arcs are not displaying in the snapshot. the uiview is showing as default and the arcs and rounds rectcorners are not displaying. Here is code for  snapshot
  CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(bottomview.frame.size.width, bottomview.frame.size.height);

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);
    [bottomview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    resultImageView.image=image;
```

and here is code for making arc
 UIBezierPath *aPathbottom = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

```
[aPathbottom moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 262)];





[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 15)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 6)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40, 3.5)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(60, 6)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(70, 10)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(80,15)];

[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(80, 250)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(70, 256)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(60, 260.5)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 264)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(55, 264.5)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40, 265)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(45, 264.5)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40, 264)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 260.5)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 256)];
[aPathbottom addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 250)];
[aPathbottom closePath];


CAShapeLayer *maskLayerbottom = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayerbottom.frame = bottomview.bounds;
maskLayerbottom.path = aPathbottom.CGPath;


bottomview.layer.mask = maskLayerbottom;
```

i don't know why it is happening.Can any one help me.

regards 
chakshu arora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer I tried
 `[bottomview.layer addSublayer:maskLayerbottom];` on place of   `bottomview.layer.mask = maskLayerbottom;` and the snapshot from the `UIView` is displaying arcs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this ?

```
[bottomview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```